# Unexpected Identifier exception while using html-webpack-plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack

[image]

I am following a tutorial and installed the plugin and updated the config file but it is showing error ": expected" in config file and  unexpected identifier when I run npm command.

I am not able to figure out issue .Please help me as I am new to this can't figure out.

Regards,
Nagasree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you specify the wrong type for `plugins`, it's supposed to be an array instead of an literal object:

```
plugins: [
  new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
    // ...
  }),
]
```